# Excel 2010 Conditional Formatting

Tags: conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet for taskers with due dates.  I have used conditional formatting to change the font color to red for pass due and yellow for approaching due dates...now i need to add another condition to change the font in the same column back to black when i input the completion date in the next column.  Due Date is in Column E and Completion Date is in Column F.  Any help with the formula will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine conditions by using a Rule Type option of "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". So, say your original rule was to set the cell to be yellow if it's within 10 days of today. That would be:

> =(E2 - TODAY()  < 10)

To add a condition to ignore the rule if the completion date has been set (i.e. something in column F), use the AND function like this:

```
=AND((E2 - TODAY()  < 10),F2="")
```

To be complete you would want to include a check to ignore this rule for past days:

> =AND((E2- TODAY()  < 10),E2 - TODAY() >0,F2="")

The rule for past uncompleted tasks is easier:

> =AND(TODAY() >= E2,F2="")

Unfortunately, Excel doesn't seem to allow relative references in conditional formulas, so you'll have to paste this in other cells one by one, instead of by a range. (There is probably an alternative way to apply this to a range?)